Build SSIS project from ADO
I'm helping our development team to build and deploy SSIS project from Azure DevOps. I'm new to SSIS and this is my first time.
When building the project, it is erroring out because it is looking for a DEV.dtproj file
Any idea what could be causing this issue?
Here is the YAML task
- task: SSISBuild@1
  inputs:
    projectPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/<projectname>'
    stripSensitive: false
    outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\<projectname>'

06/12/2024 16:20:29 Build project <Build.SourcesDirectory>\obj\Development\<someproject>.dtproj successfully.

06/12/2024 16:20:29 Start to build project <Build.SourcesDirectory>\obj\Development\<someproject>DEV.dtproj

##[error]06/12/2024 16:20:29 Could not find file <Build.SourcesDirectory>\obj\Development\<someproject>DEV.dtproj.


Double-check the paths and the file names. Can you show us the checkout task(s)?

Resolved after I provided the full path including the file name of the dtproj in projectPath. I previously had just the folder name

According to the task, it shows the description of projectPath:

Path of the project folder or file to be built. If a folder path is specified, SSIS Build task will search all dtproj files recursively under this folder and build them all.


This is why it is building more than one dtproj file and gets the error when you only provided the folder name.
